# dont get how to make connection

Tags: python, django

Ive got this models and I want to make a shopping list that have a username registered in auth_user DB, he can create a list_name and a sohppinList, i.e. bellow.
Im interesting how to make connection between them.
Someone can help me?

```
class Item(models.Model):
    username = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    list_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)


class ShoppingList (models.Model):
    list_name = models.ManyToManyField(Item)
    item = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    checkbox = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Comment: I advise you to google 'foreign keys sql'

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/models/

Comment: Given a ShoppingList instance `shopping_list`, you can do `shopping_list.list_name.all()` to get all items in the `shopping_list`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rather design models in this way:

```
class ShoppingList (models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name="user_shoplist")
    list_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    # your other fields...

class Item(models.Model):
    from_list = models.ForeignKey(ShoppingList, related_name="list_items") 
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    # more fields..



#user actions
user = request.user
user_shoplist = user.user_shoplist.create(list_name="Dolls")

#adding items to shopping list
new_item1 = user_shoplist.list_items.create(item_name='barbie')
new_item2 = user_shoplist.list_items.create(item_name='teddy')
#.... etc etc


# all shopping lists of a user
user_shopping_lists = user.user_shoplist.all()

#all items in a shopping list of a user ("user_shoplist" from above)
all_items_in_a_shoppinglist = user_shoplist.list_items.all()
```

hope, this helps

**UPDATE**: you need to add shoplist object to Item object during save process like this..

```
def create(request): 
   if request.method == 'POST': 
    form = ItemForm(request.POST) 
    if form.is_valid(): 
      # the shoplist object
      form.save(commit=False)
      form.cleaned_date['from_list'] = your_shoplist_object
      form.save()
#...
#...
```

Comment: Ive made this, but in my view I put the list name from a form and its says from_list_id column cannot be null, how I correct this?

Comment: def create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ItemForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/polls/items/')
    c = {}
    c.update(csrf(request))
    c['form'] = ItemForm()
    return render_to_response('polls/create.html', c,
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))

And the form:

class ItemForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ['list_name', ]

Comment: @capcapi during save, you need to commit=False and assign shoplist to item and then save. Item without shoppinglist doesnot also make sense, right?

Comment: I get it! 
But the commit=False, will not save in my DB?

Comment: @CapCapi yes, ``.save(commit=False)`` willnot save in db, so that you can assign shoplist inbetween, and then you do ``.save()`` again to save into db

Comment: yes, Ive done it! 
Thanks a lot!
You can help me with something else?
I cant do the filter correctly

I have this in my view..
 user = request.user
    infos = User.objects.filter(user_shoplist__user__exact=user)

And I cant make it return my list_name..
Whats wrong?

Comment: @CapCapi just do this:``shoplists = user.user_shoplist.all()``. and then you can loop over ``shoplists`` and get listname of each shoplist.

Comment: @CapCapi let me know if you need further help

Comment: When u said shoplist object, what do you mean?

Comment: @CapCapi I mean by that the instance of a shoplist class. (shoplist = ShoppingList.objects.get(list_name=""toys). here the ``shoplist`` is an object of ShoppingList class )

Comment: Ive checked and when I create a list, in shoppinglist DB, it will not insert the list_name as I put.
That could be a reason why I cant see the list_name of the User?

Comment: I want to take the list_name that I put in Item DB

Comment: @CapCapi yes, this can be the reason. make sure, you have shoplist object during saving the item object, so that both can get the relationship and so that your query can work

Comment: And my object how it will look:
 shoplist = ShoppingList.objects.get(user=request.user)
Somethin like this?

Answer (score 0):

You're heading in the right direction. But seem to have a few things slightly confused. If I was trying to create shopping lists that were owned by a user and contained items I would go about it something like this:

```
class ShoppingList (models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='shopping_lists')
    name = models.TextField()

class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    list_name = models.ForeignKey(ShoppingList, related_name='items')
```

This would let you use the models in your code like this:

```
sl = ShoppingList(user=request.user, name='Christmas Shopping List')
sl.save()
for name in ('socks', 'coal', 'glow sticks'):
    sl.items.append(Item.objects.create(name=name))
```

Then you might use your user in a console like this:

```
for s_list in user.shopping_lists.all():
    print s_list.items
```